# How can I start a Jupyter kernel that inherits environment variables (per VS Code documentation)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

At the Visual Studio Code documentation below (see link at bottom of this post) is a section called Launching/Starting kernels (meaning Jupyter kernels). There's a step that says, "activate conda environment, then scrape the environment variables for the process. Next start the kernel using those environment variables". The doc goes on to say, "This is required so that the Python kernel will inherit the same environment variables available when you launch python after activating the conda environment."

I imagine "scrape the environment variables" means to get them or list them.

- How does one do this?
- Which environment variables are we talking about? Windows system environment variables? Windows user environment variables? The results of running the command `conda env config vars list` after activating a conda environment, which may return nothing?

How does one then "start the kernel **using those environment variables**"? How do you make the Python kernel inherit the same environment variables that are available when launching python after activating the conda environment? The language of the documentation and lack of an explicit example confuse me.

I saw in argv for my conda environment's kernel spec the following

```
[
  "C:/Users/stephen/.conda/envs/py10\\python.exe",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ]
```

After activating the environment the way I normally do (`conda activate py10` in this case), I can do `python -m ipykernel_launcher`. But I do not know how to specify the connection file with the -f option that is also part of the argv. Seems I know the name of the connection file only after running the launcher (e.g., the output of `python -m ipykernel_launcher` is

```
To connect another client to this kernel, use:
    --existing kernel-2692.json
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to figure out how to do the above in VS Code console and the pick the launched kernel in the kernel picker after I open a notebook file (.ipynb).

[link to VS Code kernel discovery doc](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/General-overview-of-Kernel-Discovery-&-Execution-in-Jupyter-(&-extension)#4-listing-python-environments-as-kernels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This GitHub issue by Microsoft (at link below) appears to be at least one way to make environment variables available to a Jupyter kernel: adding the variables to an .env file in the opened folder. They are then available via os.getenv().
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/10928

See also the section on environment variables in the context of Python environments in VS Code, here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variables